# Защита Копирайта в шаблоне joomla

Tags: авторские-права, шаблоны, joomla

В одном из шаблонов для CMS joomla заменил "проверку" на подлинность копирайта. 
Вот код из index.php шаблона. При изменении копирайта - `The template will break if author link is removed.`И ничего не отображается.

```
<div id="bottom">
            <div class="tg">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="copyright"/>2011. <?php if ($this->params->get( 'footerdisable' )) : ?><?php echo ($footertext); ?><?php endif; ?></div></div>
<!-- Link protected by copyright law. DO NOT REMOVE! --><div class="lls">Powered by <a href="http://www.Сайт_производителя.com/" title="joomla 1.7 templates" target="_blank">Joomla 1.7 Templates</a></div>
</div>
```

Как убрать эту проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как убрать проверку: закомментить весь этот кусок с `eval(...);` из `functions.php`.

Не удивляйтесь внезапно начавшемуся космическому поносу: это автор может направить вам лучи.

Answer (score 1):

> Как убрать эту проверку?

Сделав то, что написано в лицензионном соглашении, если такая возможность предусмотрена (например, заплатить etc).

Answer (score 0):

В файле `functions.php` нашел интересную строку :

```
eval(str_rot13('shapgvba purpx_sbbgre(){$y=\'<n uers="uggc://jjj.serfuwbbzyngrzcyngrf.pbz/" gvgyr="wbbzyn 1.7 grzcyngrf" gnetrg="_oynax">Wbbzyn 1.7 Grzcyngrf</n>\';$s=qveanzr(__SVYR__).\'/vaqrk.cuc\';$sq=sbcra($s,\'e\');$p=sernq($sq,svyrfvmr($s));spybfr($sq);vs(fgecbf($p, $y)==0){rpub \'Gur grzcyngr jvyy oernx vs nhgube yvax vf erzbirq.\';qvr;}}purpx_sbbgre();'));
```

После расшифровывания `str_rot13` получилось

```
'function check_footer(){$l=\'<a href="http://www.freshjoomlatemplates.com/" title="joomla 1.7 templates" target="_blank">Joomla 1.7 Templates</a>\';$f=dirname(__FILE__).\'/index.php\';$fd=fopen($f,\'r\');$c=fread($fd,filesize($f));fclose($fd);if(strpos($c, $l)==0){echo \'The template will break if author link is removed.\';die;}}check_footer();'
```

Но как проверку убрать так и не понял. нужный копирайт зашифровал и изменил в index.php шаблона, все работает.